# Android Imageview with different sizes while maintaing aspect ratio

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-glide

We have an app in which we have to show feeds where each feed contain image with different sizes. I want to make the image height should be less than or at least 60% of actual device screen.So full feed will be visible.

As i am experimenting with different sizes of images, everything works fine but when vertical image uploaded its gets behind toolbar and full feed is not visible.  I dont want to crop image.

Comment: Can you give more clarification? Do you want to resize or crop the image

Comment: you can change scale type of image.. @ Can you used this??

Answer (score 0):

Privide ScaleType FIT_XY, it will scale image to x and y dimensions, irrespective of aspect ratio.

Refer this code:

```
vMainLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
vMainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

vImage = new ImageView(context);
vImage.setId(0);
vImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
vImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.fitXY);
vImage.setLayoutParams(params1);
vImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_circles_en); 

vMainLayout.addView(vImage);
```

Either you can change in XML code:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ConstraintLayout` you could simply add the property `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` to your `ImageView`.